# sshpass failing with exit code 6

Tags: ssh

My setup is the following:

- node `A` is where I start
- node `B` is the gateway machine
- node `C` is the destination.

From `A`to `B` I have setup SSH public key authentication but from `B` to `C` I am not allowed to.

So from node `A` I use the following incantation which actually works from a different machine (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sshpass -p secretpass ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p username@B" username@C
```

… however, when I try from a different location with another machine (Ubuntu 16.04 - though I doubt that's relevant), the invocation of `sshpass` promptly returns without any kind of output and an exit code (obtained with `echo $?`) of 6.

More puzzling is the fact that if I do the steps separately, they succeed:

```
A: $ ssh username@B   (directly access B without being prompted for password)
B: $ ssh username@C   (prompted for password, provided 'secretpass')
C: $                  (reached my destination)
```

Comment: I don't have a similar setup to test, but will `ssh -A -t username@B sshpass -p secretpass ssh -A username@C` work?

Comment: `sshpass` is not available on node `B` nor can I install it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out what was the matter. Since I was using this script for the first time on this machine I had to first do the following (without `sshpass`):

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p username@B" username@C
```

I was then prompted with:

> The authenticity of host 'C <no hostip for proxy command>)' can't be established.
>
> RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:... .
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
>
> Warning: Permanently added 'C' (RSA) to the list of known hosts

… once I accepted the above, I was able to use the incantation I inquire about in my question without further problems.

So this failure was due to the incantation not being able to answer to the authenticity prompt that only appears once.

From the man page of `sshpass` (RETURN VALUE section):

> As with any other program, sshpass returns 0 on success. In case of failure, the following return codes are used:
> [...]
> `6`      Host public key is unknown. sshpass exits without confirming the new key.

Comment: Please remember to log in once with all used users. At first I only did it with a normal user and then wondered why the script (executed with sudo/root!) didn't work. -_-